# How SMS numbers for services work?

Tags: sms

Not sure if this is the place for the question, but...

I did receive spam sms from a number, about a promotion here in Brazil. And, from this same number (27900), I did receive my Evernote verification code.

Now I wonder, is there some 'free for use', or rentable, sms numbers for anyone to send anything?

Comment: Sorry, questions about mobile phones and related infrastructure are off-topic at Super User. Maybe ask Evernote support what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite "free for use". But, there *are* companies such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) which specialize in providing APIs for sending SMS messages, so that individual web apps won't need to make agreements with dozens of telephone operators anymore.

Such services will usually route all messages (even from different customers) sent towards the same regio through the same phone number. For example, I live in Central Europe and various services – Tumblr, Blizzard, eBay, Namecheap – send me security codes via +44.7781470659. (According to the web, even Google and Microsoft use the same gateway.)